Error: Could not fetch bytecode for contract at 0x20775d300BdE943Ac260995E977fb915fB01f399 on chain 137
    import { ThirdwebProvider, metamaskWallet, coinbaseWallet, walletConnect, phantomWallet } from           '   @thirdweb-dev/react';
    import { createThirdwebClient, getContract, resolveMethod } from 'thirdweb';
    import { defineChain } from 'thirdweb/chains';
    import { StateContextProvider } from './context';


    // Create the Thirdweb client with your clientId
    const client = createThirdwebClient({
      clientId: "bf783e8afe4c2547a9373fc7770da66e"
    });

    // Connect to your contract
    const contract = getContract({
      client,
      chain: defineChain(137),
      address: "0x20775d300BdE943Ac260995E977fb915fB01f399"
    });

    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

    root.render(
        <ThirdwebProvider 
        client={client}
    supportedWallets={[
        metamaskWallet({
            recommended: true,
        }),
    coinbaseWallet(),
    walletConnect(),
    ]}
    activeChain={'polygon'}
     clientId="bf783e8afe4c2547a9373fc7770da66e"
    >
        <Router>
            <StateContextProvider contract_info={contract}>
                <App />
            </StateContextProvider>
        </Router>
    </ThirdwebProvider>
    ) 

I have this code in my main.jsx. When i try const { contract } = useContract(contractAddress); in my stateContextProvider, i receive this error in my browser console.
console.js:273 Error: Could not fetch bytecode for contract at 0x20775d300BdE943Ac260995E977fb915fB01f399 on chain 137, double check that the address and chainId are correct.
at fetchContractMetadataFromBytecode (chunk-D5XVISX3.js?v=c52aa177:27087:11)
at async fetchContractMetadataFromAddress (chunk-D5XVISX3.js?v=c52aa177:27060:16)
The code below us the code for my StateContextProvider
    export const StateContextProvider = ({ children, contract_info }) => { 
      console.log(contract_info.address);
      console.log(contract_info.chain);
      onsole.log(contract_info.client);
      const contractAddress = contract_info.address
      const { contract } = useContract(contractAddress);

      const { mutateAsync: createCampaign } = useContractWrite(contract, 'createCampaign');  

        const address = useAddress(); //getting the address for our wallet
        const publishCampaign = async (form) => {
        try {
          const data = await createCampaign([
            address, // owner
            form.title, // title
            form.description, // description
            form.target,
            new Date(form.deadline).getTime(), // deadline,
            form.image,
          ])

           console.log("contract call success", data)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("contract call failure", error)
        }
      }

      return (     
        <StateContext.Provider  
          value={{ 
            address,
            contract,
            createCampaign: publishCampaign,
          }}
        >
          {children} //we have to render the children in between our context state provider
        </StateContext.Provider>
      )
    }


I have confirmed that the contract address i have used is the right one from #thirdweb. I have also ensured the contractAddress is passed into my stateContextProvider by logging it to console. The code below is my stateContextprovider. I have confirmed that chain137 is my desired chain which is The Polygon network.
I do not expect to see that error, because of it,I cannot Create a Campaign succesfully.
